# Handling event of static class

Tags: vb.net, static, event-handling

I have a problem with basics of events in VB.NET. I want to have a static class but in VB.NET it doesn´t exist, equivalent is `Module`. So I have a module and inside of it there are some properties (static of course). Example:

```
Public Module MyModule

   Private _value As Integer
   Public Event ValueChanged()

   Public Property Value() As Integer
      Get
         Return _value
      End Get
      Set(ByVal value As Integer)
         _value = value
         RaiseEvent ValueChanged()
      End Set
   End Property

End Module
```

In my situation I want to handle changed `_value`. This code should be OK. But If I want to handle it inside another class:

```
Public Class MyClass

   Public Sub Method_ValueChanged() Handles MyModule.ValueChaged
        'Do something...
   End Sub

End Class
```

Here is a problem because MyModule must be declared as `WithEvents` but MyModule is static so can´t do that. Can you tell me how I can handle an event of static class from another class? Thank you.

Comment: Static in VB.NET is [`Shared`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zc2b427x.aspx). A module is similar to a static class in C# but you don't need a module to define shared methods or fields.

Comment: Sorry for that, normally I work in C#...

Comment: to get something similar to a static class in vb.net i would recommend to make a NotInheritable class with private constructor and only shared functions.

Comment: @SilvioMarcovic: You can also stay with a module. That's also a NotInheritable class which you cannot instatiate with shared members only. It's also mandatory for extension methods.

Comment: yeah true that, there are lot of discussions about what to use. module or static class. both options are fine i guess. 

except for extensions as you mentioned.

most of the time c# to vb.net converter convert static classes to NotInheritable classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `AddHandler`.

Example:

```
Module A
    Private _value As Integer
    Public Event ValueChanged()

    Public Property Value() As Integer
    Get
        Return _value
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _value = value
        RaiseEvent ValueChanged()
    End Set
    End Property
End Module

Module B
    Sub Main
        AddHandler ValueChanged, AddressOf Method_ValueChanged
        A.Value = 12
    End Sub

    Public Sub Method_ValueChanged()
        Console.WriteLine("Changed!")
    End Sub
End Module
```

running this will print `Changed!`.